# Handle audiojack button

Tags: android

I I bought this [Key Quick Button Pressy Dustproof Plug Earphone Jack Plug](http://www.ebay.com/itm/171374260571?ssPageName=STRK:MEWNX:IT&_trksid=p3984.m1497.l2649) and I would like develop apps for this.

How can I handle the click as a service or broadcast in Android so run some logic on click?

This [android official blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.ar/2010/06/allowing-applications-to-play-nicer.html) not working. I'm using 4.0+

This is [my code](https://mycodestock.com/public/snippet/12222)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be what's called a Media Button, and it does cause a system broadcast that can be handled by a BroadcastReceiver, but it needs to be implemented a little differently than regular Receivers. Only one app at a time can receive the broadcast, and the Receiver must be registered with `AudioManager` to become active. [This developer page](http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/volume-playback.html#PlaybackControls) demonstrates how to implement and register the Receiver. However, there are several misprints in that section. The System Service needs to be cast as `AudioManager`, and the `registerMediaButtonEventReceiver()` and `unregisterMediaButtonEventReceiver()` methods' calls should each have a `ComponentName` object as the parameter. For example:

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);  
ComponentName receiverName = new ComponentName(mContext, RemoteControlReceiver.class);
...
// Start listening for button presses
am.registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(receiverName);
...

// Stop listening for button presses
am.unregisterMediaButtonEventReceiver(receiverName);
```

Comment: The snippets look ok. Did you try the app that's written for the gadget to make sure it works? Have you debugged to see if your `onReceive()` method is being called?

Comment: Yes. I debug the code, and never called de onRecibe. The gadget app looks fine.

Comment: When I press the button without the app of the button or mine, its executes Google Now. Strange.

Comment: here is the problem. is 

"(intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON"))"

instead of

"(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.equals(intent.getAction()))"

Comment: So, `onReceive()` was being called?

Comment: yes. I removed all the if condition to see better the debug.

Comment: Twice event with one click

Log.d("nulos",""+event.getKeyCode()); >> 79 /// 
Log.d("nulos",""+event.getAction());  >> 0 ///

Log.d("nulos",""+event.getKeyCode()); >> 79 ///
Log.d("nulos",""+event.getAction());  >> 1 ///